# How to measure the VA rating of a step down transformer

Tags: transformer

I have an uncased, unlabeled step-down transformer which converts 240 UK voltage to 112v (I have measured this with a meter). It weighs 1.5kg, is 10 x 8 x 10.5cms including the attached 2-pin US socket. How can I determine it's maximum VA rating?

Comment: As a half decent approximation compare its weight against catalogue transformers of a similar size.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the transformer? Does it have a type plate?

Comment: Isn't UK mains 230V nowadays, like the rest of Europe?

Answer (score 2):

You can never be sure without the datasheet of the manufacturer.

Rule of thumb for a non-welded iron EI core: 50 VA/kg.

[This is a nice tool](http://www.sklaic.info/electronics/transformer/transformer.php).